# Vertically align a text with an image inside a div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I saw a similar post to this which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109308/vertically-align-left-aligned-text-with-right-aligned-image/) but I noticed that no one answered and that when I do press the jsfiddle, it doesn't center it.

I have this current code and what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the image directly in the middle vertically inside the div. I've tried vertical-align and putting it in span and top % but nothing seems to work. I'm also using Chrome so I don't know if that matters.
http://jsfiddle.net/y84mx/

```
    <div class="hours">
    <div id="sun">
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="Opening" height="auto" width="20%" align="left" vertical-align="middle" />
        <span>Hours</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: #sun {line-height: 15px;}  http://jsfiddle.net/y84mx/6/

Comment: note that attributes like `align` and `vertical-align` are deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#sun {
    position:relative;
}

img {
    background: #3A6F9A;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y84mx/4/)**

Comment: erm... nothing is changing there... i see the image on the left hand side and text on the right hand side, both on top (OSX / Chrome) - i'm **not** the OP...

Comment: Did you check the demo?

Comment: Then use the inspector tools and you'll see that the image is vertical align inside the parent div.

Comment: well, yeah, though this doesn't demonstrate the behaviour very well, especially as you are not giving any explanation... i'd apply a border or something, if I was you...

Comment: This and Gaurav's post worked but I love how you worked around my html code rather than changing things up (since I did omit a good portion of my code). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For both items set `display: inline-block;`
Then make sure to match the `line-height` of the `<span>` the height of the image.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/2jpDw/5/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div id="hours"> 
    <span id="sun"> 
        <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" alt="twibuffer"  /> 
    </span>  
    <span> Hours</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hours {
    margin-bottom:2%;
    text-align: center;
}
#hours span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#hours #sun {
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* to show the centering */
}
```

Comment: This worked as well (at least for my purposes). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y84mx/7/), Please check

```
#sun{
 line-height : auto;
 border: 1px solid;
 text-align : center;  
}

.hours{
padding-left: 2%;
padding-right: 2%;
text-align: right;
color: #000;
font-size: 40px;
}

img {
  background: #3A6F9A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this
http://jsfiddle.net/chetangawai/y84mx/9/

```
#sun{
  text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid
}

.hours{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;

}

img {
     background: #3A6F9A;
}
```